# TypeError: Unhashable type: 'Dict' when trying to add a dictionary to a set

Tags: python

What is trying to be hashed  and what is the reason behind the error TypeError: Unhashable type: 'Dict'. I searched through other questions, but no clear answer is available.

```
a = set()
for x in (1, 2, {'A':'bad'}):
    print(x)
    a.add(x) # Error is here
print(a)
```

And the console output is in the following way:

```
1
2
{'A': 'bad'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    a.add(x)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'


** Process exited - Return Code: 1 **
Press Enter to exit terminal
```

I'm trying to recursively parse through XML where there are multiple tags inside another and I try them to put in a dictionary where the value of any key is of type "set",inturn can contain any number of dictionaries.

I ended up with this TypeError and now when I had written a sample code on why this happened, and I'm not able to figure out why a dictionary cannot be added to a set.

Comment: `{'A':'bad'}` is a dictionary. `a` is a set. Adding items to a set requires them to be hashed. Dictionaries can't be hashed. That's exactly what the error is telling you

Comment: *"I'm not able to figure out why a dictionary cannot be added to a set"* - as the error clearly states, it is not hashable. If it is not clear what that means, you can check the duplicate question. If you still don't understand, please [edit] your question to focus on a specific problem: explain exactly what don't you understand that is not covered in the duplicate (or any tutorial) or otherwise give a [mre] with input and your expected output

Comment: @roganjosh: I got it. Instead of dictionary, if I use some immutable types like namedtuple it started to work.